# Convert database definition files into SQL

Tags: mysql, database

I'm interested in analyzing some of the virus definition files used by antivirus software. All of them provide free access to the databases, but all the one's I've found so far are in some kind of in-house data file format (.AVC for Kaspersky Anti-virus, etc).

Is there any software that uses a data format closer to MySQL, or can any of these in-house data files be converted?

Comment: Can't see this being readily available.  The engine changes because people profile how AV itself works.  Best of luck though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/) virus definitions, which are in an open format (as ClamAV itself is open source).

There appears to be some documentation of [how to create signatures](http://www.clamav.net/doc/latest/signatures.pdf).

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Open source to the rescue again! Any idea how to convert the signed files into plaintext?

Comment: @MarathonStudios: Not sure how to convert them, but I'd dig around the source some, I'd guess the chance of a debug util to do that as being pretty high. (Or at least it'll probably be pretty easy to write)